# Why can we write Groovy code in Java syntax?

Tags: java, testing, groovy

I'm just new at Groovy and a few years experience on Java. I'm following a simple tutorial said 95% of Groovy syntax are same as Java. So I am wondering is that a good practice to write your Groovy code as Java? And why not?

thanks

Comment: That sounds like replacing a manual screwdriver with an electrical one just to use it like a manual one ;)

Comment: @cfrick this is how something like C++ took off.

Answer (score 1):

You can write Groovy code in Java syntax to make it easy for Java developers to move to Groovy: as this language feature allows them to start by writing code as they know how to, or they can copy/paste existing Java code into a groovy script.

In other words: the groovy language was designed on purpose to allow for this, to help attracting users.

Looking at pros and cons:

- The big advantage of writing java-like groovy code is simple: in case you get unhappy with groovy, it is easier for you to move back. And it allows your team members/coworker who haven't learned groovy to understand your work.
- The downside: the whole point of groovy is to give you some features that Java is lacking, so to an experienced groovy programmer, "too much java" style might trigger the question: "why using groovy when you write pure Java all the time?"

Beyond that, keep in mind that groovy is really more of a niche language, that never gained a lot of attention (outside the gradle build eco system).

From that point of view, my personal two cents: don't write groovy code in the first place. Even gradle can be used with *kotlin* these days. Unless you get paid for doing so, rather spend your time and energy with other languages, e.g. kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

"Is that a good practice to write your Groovy code as Java?"

You mean using a Groovy compiler to compile your Java code? Why would you do that?

Although Groovy supports Java syntax, it's mostly intended for simplifying and compacting your code, providing Groovy programming idioms and syntactic sugar. If you're just a beginner, it's ok to **combine** Groovy and Java code while you're learning Groovy syntax. But ultimately you **should** use Groovy syntax only.

So the answer to your question: no, it's not a good practise to write Groovy code as Java.

Comment: *You mean using a Groovy compiler to compile your Java code? Why would you do that?* If you have a mixed code base and want to prevent circular reference problems, it's easier to put also the .java files in your .groovy source set since groovyc delegates to javac for them.

Comment: Yep, in this case it would make sense. But I think the question is more about writing Java code thinking "I'm coding in Groovy"